# how to use grafana query value in javascript

Tags: javascript, grafana

How can I use the result of a grafana query math expression in a javascript that is in the same visualization as the query, e.g.

Math expression that does give one float number as result:

[image]

Now I would like to use this result or the query name `pdiff_mean` in a javascript that is in the same visualization (Dynamic Text panel).

[image]

The above simple script gives for now `pdiff_mean is not defined`.

Any idea how this can work to use query names in the javascript?

Comment: The label mentions handlebars. Did you try `console.log({{pdiff_mean}})`? I don't have Grafana ready to test

Comment: This gives me the error `expected property name, got '{'`.

Comment: Not familiar with this plugin, but usually to use variable whereever you want to use it, you should use variable syntax: any of `$var`, `${var}`, `[[var]]`. Can you try something like `console.log($pdiff_mean)`?

Comment: All those syntax variants don't work. I am not sure what I am missing.